# How do I fix a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm making a game but when i tried to launch it it said: `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Here is the code:

```
package com.shinxs.rain.graphics;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Screen {

    private int width, height;
    public int[] pixels;
    Graphics g;

    public int[] tiles = new int[64 * 64];

    private Random random = new Random();

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("Resources/Inventory.png");
    Image image = i.getImage();

    public Screen(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int[width * height];

        for (int i = 0; i < 64 * 64; i++) {
            tiles[i] = random.nextInt(0xFFFFFF);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0;
        }       
    }

    public void render() {
        g.drawImage(image, 500, 200, 124, 280, null);
    }
}
```

Please tell me if you know how to fix it, I've been stuck with it for a long time.

Comment: First out, find and study the exception traceback.  It will tell you most of what you need to know.

Comment: [Why did you tag this javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5184356/396458)

Comment: Please read some java, default values for object properties for instance...

Comment: If you get any further exceptions, please post it here with a stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Graphics g;
```

Your `g` is pointing to *null-reference* and you are calling `drawImage` on null which is resulting in NPE (`NullPointerException`).

```
g.drawImage(image, 500, 200, 124, 280, null);
```

See this tutorial on [how to use Graphics in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your Graphics object is null because you never assign to any other value. Null means that an object is "empty" and contains no data, which is a logical value for objects to be initialized to. In order to use a Graphics object, you need to get access to a pre-made one, as the Graphics class has no public constructor (new Graphics() does not work). The only way I know of to do this is to extend javax.swing.JFrame and override the paint(Graphics g), in which a pre-instantiated Graphics object is passed as an argument. The Graphics object is created by the internal workings of the JFrame.

```
   class Screen extends javax.swing.JFrame{

         public void paint(Graphics g){
                super.paint(g); //correctly draws background

                //now call methods on g, the graphics object
         }
   }
```

I would highly recommend looking into the documentation on Swing, to find out more about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you never initialiazed your Graphics g;object and calling methods on it,
you have to initialize your Graphics object, otherwise it'd be null, as objects default value is *null*.

```
Graphics g= Griphics.create();

g.darwLine()
```